# Heroku Spotify Auth/Callback error (Logs attached)

Tags: api, redirect, logging, heroku, spotify

What is wrong? This works on my localhost:3000 but crashes on Heroku. Heroic is telling me this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJQlW.png

The github is here: https://github.com/gmaijoe/crowdtune

```
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002893+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002897+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:48879
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002898+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002899+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002900+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:18:21.415886 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002900+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:18:21.509675 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002901+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:18:25.498594 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002902+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:18:25.583259 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002903+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:19:34.028206 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002903+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:19:34.107705 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002904+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:19:34.611176 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Callback phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002906+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:19:54.515708 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Callback phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002905+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:19:54.301895 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002905+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:19:54.208356 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002907+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:20:38.052902 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002908+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:20:38.123414 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002908+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:20:38.509740 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Callback phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002909+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:28:26.834043 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002910+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:28:26.915001 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002911+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-12-24T17:28:27.384754 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Callback phase initiated.
2015-12-24T17:33:35.002912+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-12-24T17:33:35.617120+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in <top (required)> at /app/config/environments/production.rb:32)
2015-12-24T17:33:36.062711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-12-24T17:33:36.578932+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-12-24 17:33:36] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-12-24T17:33:36.578941+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-12-24 17:33:36] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2015-12-24T17:33:36.579310+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-12-24 17:33:36] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=14781
2015-12-24T17:33:38.202638+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=96ee92ea-425b-452b-b8bb-d8b2794039a9 fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=152ms status=200 bytes=2368
2015-12-24T17:33:38.211889+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=c6beda50-cb49-4c07-a3a8-ed494c50e2ae fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=2368
2015-12-24T17:33:38.322392+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1aa3c68284e535e6bd990e0ab9d53daa20eafffffb193121721c11b8c1ec0e07.css" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=c0b46775-aab1-4e04-8f19-c1f1c704ca70 fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-12-24T17:33:38.333716+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1aa3c68284e535e6bd990e0ab9d53daa20eafffffb193121721c11b8c1ec0e07.css" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=f18ebf07-10f5-4196-9d1f-ffb982913010 fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-12-24T17:33:38.455225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-3957e560437f754d34f092b45bf32545a7f875191a04d6dd773c79b3536bacb2.js" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=5b380f64-a1c9-4cfd-b3e2-7386fd06f13a fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-12-24T17:33:38.973286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/cliff.jpeg" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=3fcdacc0-ef97-4d8f-8d09-427facbf4e35 fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=464ms status=304 bytes=343
2015-12-24T17:33:38.982291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/cliff.jpeg" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=549d2700-8a45-4ec8-b321-35077e6d94e5 fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=440ms status=304 bytes=343
2015-12-24T17:33:38.450911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-3957e560437f754d34f092b45bf32545a7f875191a04d6dd773c79b3536bacb2.js" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=70994a07-a528-4613-aa80-b99da63023b0 fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-12-24T17:33:41.490454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/spotify" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=afaa4b36-b2c7-4cb9-b2a3-9b55bc04ccff fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=12ms service=26ms status=302 bytes=1534
2015-12-24T17:33:41.572681+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/spotify" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=e6d2e428-0e77-4aa4-9a2f-e1740267d159 fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=302 bytes=1534
2015-12-24T17:33:42.887686+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/spotify/callback?code=AQAtAOLDTXmIXe8wj0OsAWcVQtFFd2V8OuvSczxL_OJFgoQIHDpN49ooruln1rvrFtKqGskR190Hq7kUjRtE0m6q1z4I8vN0jsIufj1vEKDKLsjvAyIK3ForrjAOqY6A4r_7em7NUhEZrGOS1xlnbecIdkiKL1ZzqH3G1Na8KBMTBjFJflMmSSkhBwJr1kiXtG0sBOynQcLvi-jZfGEYrwpL9BtGMI5mZomt6OEvAKcBhFYW5v2M6Tgehk3rCx2XoPzDjU87U7QTHOOfc28RYeiCJjqZKCvttO-0ncFO02tLQFhVsU-M6zlpdWNl1Nq83WSrPosH7L34USyMlcYeRYhx&state=ba6b223061d5abff30f6734a1270cad02d79e682adaee6ad" host=vast-gorge-2774.herokuapp.com request_id=93121448-c5aa-482f-a3d7-de9085c5f4f1 fwd="97.86.245.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=831ms status=500 bytes=1754
```